# I have an iPad 2, it is not charging at all. What can I do? I have tried a different charger,

Tags: ipad

Everything I need to say is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could be a simple issue, your charge port maybe full of dust / dirt. 
Get a wooden cocktail stick and gently remove the dirt from the charge point, this will allow your charger to hit your iPad's charge connection points.